# Replacing Select Dataframe Columns (based on other conditions) Issue

Tags: python, pandas, replace

### Replacing Select Dataframe Columns (based on other conditions) Issue

```
df.loc[df.gender=='boy',:]['names'] = df.loc[df.gender=='boy',:]['names'].replace(',','/',regex=False)

print df (result)

    gender   names
0    boy      bob, joe
1    boy    john, nick
2   girl   sarah, ally
3   girl  maria, sally

df['names'] = df.loc[df.gender=='boy',:]['names'].replace(',','/',regex=False)

print df (result)

    gender       names
0    boy    bob, joe
1    boy  john, nick
2   girl         NaN
3   girl         NaN
```

I also tried `df['names'].str.replace(',','/',regex=False,inplace=True)`, but received the error message

> *TypeError: replace() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'*.

Desired Result

```
    gender        names
0    boy     bob/ joe
1    boy   john/ nick
2   girl  sarah, ally
3   girl maria, sally
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace : `...replace()` doesn't have an `inplace` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.loc[df.gender=='boy','names'] = df.names.str.replace(',','/')

>>> df
  gender         names
0    boy      bob/ joe
1    boy    john/ nick
2   girl   sarah, ally
3   girl  maria, sally
```

Answer (score 1):

numpy "put" and "where" method - slightly faster than the df.loc method:

```
import numpy as np

np.put(df.names, np.where(df.gender == 'boy')[0], df.names.str.replace(',', '/'))
```